# .htaccess redirect url.com/file.php?=$terms to newurl.com/search.php?=$terms if referrer is not site.com

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 video sites, one of them is a video host (`url.com`) and another is a wordpress frontend (`newurl.com`) where I embed videos from my video host.

What I want to do is disable any access to the content of the video host except my main site being able to still embed files.

I thought of doing it via using htaccess and using rule to allow access only if reffer is newurl.com else if there is no referrer or something else.

But problem is the video embed shows related videos within the video player of the embed and thats from where the users get link to the video host.

I want to do something like this.

When a user clicks a related video, he is redirected to something like this:

```
url.com/player/cbplayer/plugins/related/related_videos.php?vid=%%VID ID%%&title=%%VIDEO TITLE%%&tags=%%VIDEO TAGS%%
```

I want to redirect him to my main site like this

```
newurl.com/search.php?=%%VIDEOTITLE
```

or if Video title cant be used then atleast the whole string after `related_videos.php` itself

Basically I want to redirect my users from videohost url to a search form on my main site itself.

Also, while using Referrers I want to be safe that it doesnt redirects the embed from my main site content as well

The embed file is called `embed.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this will match all hits on `related_videos.php` (with a title querystring) but only when referrer is not `your.domain` and redirect them to `thatnewurl.com/search.php?title=oldtitle`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !your\.domain 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)title=(.*?)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule related_videos\.php http://thatnewurl.com/search.php?title=%2
```

Comment: The last line matches related_videos.php, you can also change where it rewrites to on that line.

Comment: Press Shift+Enter if you absolutely must have a newline in a comment. Also, did you try the rule?

Comment: Thanks about new line :P
Also, in 3rd line where it says your\.domain, I need to replace 
"your" with domain name and ".domain" with its tld i.e. .com right ?

It didnt worked, url still opens
Also, if it makes any diff. the related_videos.php has a path like
[link](oldurl.com/player/cbplayer/plugins/related/related_videos.php?)
My bad I missed the full path in main post

and new line doesnt works

Comment: This works on my simple test site, can you paste your full htaccess config and also try with enabling rewritelog.

Comment: Please find the htaccess in the attached pastebin link, also I have added full urls of both sites on top of htaccess    
http://pastebin.com/16EdAz7G

Comment: Yes, I removed them before pasting as they didnt worked when I tested in same htaccess

Comment: You are not really helping me help you.. Can you please post how your non-working .htaccess looks like. As I wrote, this does work on my simple test site. Did you make sure your cache was cleared when trying?

Comment: It didnt actually quite worked but still you gave me another idea to do it  Thanks for the help though :) I had to block my index.php and use headers to allow access as a turnaround way